# Is there any linux command to Keep only 5 recent files that start with REF in a folder?

Tags: linux, file, timestamp, command, aix

I would like to make a linux command which will keep only the last 5 recent files, but these files must start with REF, and delete the other files also which start with REF, but not touch the other files.
For example: in my folder, I have:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 0 Jan 1, 2022 File_0
-rw-r--r-- 1 0 Jan 1, 2022 REF_1
-rw-r--r-- 1 0 Feb 1 2022 REF_2
-rw-r--r-- 1 0 March 1, 2022 REF_3
-rw-r--r-- 1 0 Apr 1, 2022 REF_4
-rw-r--r-- 1 0 May 1, 2022 REF_5
-rw-r--r-- 1 0 June 1, 2022 REF_6
-rw-r--r-- 1 0 Jul 1, 2022 file_7
-rw-r--r-- 1 0 1 Aug 2022 file_8
-rw-r--r-- 1 0 Sep 1, 2022 REF_9
```

The command should remove only:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 0 Jan 1, 2022 REF_1
-rw-r--r-- 1 0 Feb 1 2022 REF_2
```

... and should keep the other files. I tried `ls -t REF* | head -n+4 | xargs rm REF*` but this command deletes all files that start with REF!

What command can I use?

Comment: The end of the command is simply `| xargs rm` Also`ls -1t` should be used.

Comment: You should be able to do this using the `logrotate` system. No need to reinvent the wheel

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond Do you mean ls -lt REF* | head -n+4 | xargs rm ?  I tried to but I got: 
rm: illegal option -- w
Usage: rm [-firRe] [--] File ...

Comment: @Barmar  in fact I can't use that because need to put the commad in an other system

Comment: Avoid trying to parse `ls` output. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls

Comment: @OP Be careful, it is not `ls -lt` but `ls -1t`

Comment: @MohammedAjeddig Did the comments or an answer solve your issue? If one of the answers helped, you can say thanks by up voting and/or checking that one as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Using zsh (available on many Linux distributions and also on AIX from IBM's [AIX Toolbox for Open Source Software](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/883796#Z)), you could simply:

```bash
rm REF*(om[6,-1])
```

This uses zsh's powerful globbing (filename generation) abilities to:

- gather the list of files starting with `REF`
- sort the files by their modification time (newest first) with `(om...)`
- keep the five newest files by selecting the 6th and remaining files with `[6,-1]`
- pass that list of files to `rm`

Test it first with a simple `print -l REF*(om[6,-1])` to see which files would be collected.

See [Glob Qualifiers](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) for more about zsh's glob qualifiers.

Answer (score 0):

### Logrotate was mentioned, why not use it?

It can't handlle the separator being an underscore (_).

```
$ cat log.conf
REF* {
         rotate 5
}
% logrotate log.conf
error: log.conf:1 keyword 'REF' not properly separated, found 0x2a
```

### Here is a complete script, with safe filenames.

```
find . -name 'REF_*' -print0 | \
    xargs -0 stat -c "%Y %n" | \
    sort -n | \
    head -n+3 | \
    sed -e 's/^[0-9]* //' | \
    tr '\12' '\0' | \
    xargs -0 rm
```

1. First, let us use `find` with nulls to fetch the list of files.
2. Then use `xargs` to use `stat` to prepend the unix time stamp.
3. Use `sort` to sort by oldest first.
4. Use `head` -n+3 to find all except the last 5.
5. Use `sed` to strip the temporary unix time stamp.
6. Use `tr` to convert the returns from `stat` to nulls again.
7. Finally `xargs` to delete the unwanted files.